Bundling third party library xchart in intelij plugin
My [custom] Intellij plugin uses the xchart third party library. I always get this error:

Package not found (1 problem)
Package 'org.knowm' is not found (1 problem)
Package 'org.knowm' is not found along with its 5 classes.
Probably the package 'org.knowm' belongs to a library or dependency that is not resolved by the checker.
It is also possible, however, that this package was actually removed from a dependency causing the detected problems. Access to unresolved classes at runtime may lead to NoSuchClassError.

What more can I do?
For the full code: https://github.com/ChiriacCasian/CommitScheduler6
I have added it to build.gradle, I added the .jar to project Structure -> dependencies (I put the .jar in /lib) and I am building with shadowJar with ./gradle clean build shadowJar but I cannot get it past the plugin compatibility verifier no matter what and how I build.

Are you referring to a third-party IntelliJ plugin, a custom IntelliJ plugin or a Gradle plugin? In your question you say IntelliJ plugin but you tagged the question with "gradle-plugin".

sorry about that, you are right, it has nothing to do with gradle-plugin, I am building a custom intelij plugin and am using a third party library for it. Thank you for the reply.
